# AX 2012 XDS for Custom Dimension Values

Tags: security, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a case in which I'm requested to make a record level security (**Extensible Data Security**) for a custom dimension values like "**Branch**" financial dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by the following steps:

1-  Create a query with “DimensionFinancialTag” table as the only one data source and define the “Range” with “Value” field for values as per your business needs for all the custom dimensions.
2-  In the Security policy define the “Primary table = DimensionFinancialTag”, “Constrained table = Yes”.
3-  Do not add any tables to the security policy.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good case to try out can you please give more details , like where You want the security to take effect,

Is it Master or some default dimension, please give the business scenario

Comment: I want to filter the default dimension values.